# How to Add New Members to Struct

Tags: c++, inheritance, data-structures, struct

These are functions and Struct declarations I have, and I'm not allowed to change them.

```
DerivedA giveDerivedA ();
DerivedB giveDerivedB ();

struct Base{
    QString elementId;
    QString elementType;
};

struct DerivedA : Base {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct DerivedB : Base {
    int c;
    int d;
};
```

But what I need is something like this:

```
struct DerivedA : Base {
    int a;
    int b;
    void create();
    QString doc;
};
```

How can I add these method and member to structs I got?

My first idea is:

```
struct myA: DerivedA {
    void create();
    QString doc;
};
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Edit: 2nd Alternative(Choosed)

```
struct myA{
    void create();
    QString doc;
    private:
      DerivedA derivedA;
};
```

Comment: Why do they need to be private? That will mean that nothing else can access them.

Comment: And why can't you change them?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, sorry no private, my bad, I edited.

Comment: @GMan, Because, there are in some library which I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the problem people have extending standard library classes. If your base class doesn't have a virtual destructor, you can't safely inherit from it. In that case, you must either use free-functions (preferred anyway), or composition.

Otherwise, what you have there is good.

Comment: Base class doesn't have a virtual constructor, what is the problem with inheritance in such a case?

Comment: @metdos: If you have: `struct base {}; struct derived : base {};` Then: `base* x = new derived;` becomes undefined behavior with `delete x;`. If you delete a derived type through a base pointer, the base type must have a virtual destructor. This is why you cannot inherit from (most) standard library classes.

Comment: I think you meant virtual destructor in your answer and not virtual constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Use composition or inheritance, depending on what kind of relationship the classes have (see e.g. Items 32 and 38 in Effective C++).

Comment: Thanks, I liked "is-implemented-in-terms-of".

Answer (score 0):

That ain't workin', that's the way you do it.